# Annotation-based Servlet security not taken into account

Tags: security, servlets, jakarta-ee, websphere

I'm trying to protect a servlet to only allow access to users with role `MY_ROLE` (all authenticated users are given the role `MY_ROLE`). My Servlet looks like this :

```
@WebServlet(name = "remoting", loadOnStartup = 1, urlPatterns = { "/remoting/*" })
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = { "MY_ROLE" }))
public class MyRemotingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Despite this configuration, I'm able to access the URL exposed by this Servlet without even being asked to authenticate. The only way I found to force authentication and therefore control access to the servlet is by creating a `web.xml` file with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="MyWar" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>remoting</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>remoting</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>MY_ROLE</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>MY_ROLE</role-name>
  </security-role>

</web-app>
```

My question is : is the `web.xml` file really necessary or am I doing something wrong in my servlet definition ?

Version of WebSphere 8.5.5.3.

**EDIT:**

Generated `web.xml` deployment descriptor is as follows when not provided :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="false"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

 <display-name>MyWar</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>MyRemotingServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <enabled>True</enabled>
  <async-supported>False</async-supported>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <security-role>
  <description>generated from RolesAllowed of ServletSecurity annotation</description>
  <role-name>MY_ROLE</role-name>
 </security-role>

</web-app>
```

**EDIT 2:**

The following warning is shown at startup :

> com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation
>   [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@261721818 ] for method [
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@1945169957 (
>   javax.servlet.annotation.ServletSecurity.value ) ] Name [ null ]
>   Description [ Ljavax/servlet/annotation/HttpConstraint; ] Call in
>   violation of protocol

**EDIT 3 (workaround) :**

Looks like the problem comes from the fact that I'm building and deploying my application directly from Eclipse using m2e and the IBM WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse. If I build and deploy it outside of Eclipse then it works as expected. I will try to compare the deployed artifacts and deployment descriptors between both methods to see if I can spot a difference.

Comment: This looks like a bug, same code works fine in WebSphere Liberty. You should raise a PMR.

Comment: Can you please try to add @DeclareRoles("MY_ROLE") annotation and try. I have seen mixed behavior whether declare roles is needed or not when using roles allowed annotation. Annotations should work and you  do not need to have web.xml

Comment: Did you got chance to try adding @DeclareRoles. Did that help any?

Comment: I tried indeed, the only difference is the appearence of another `<security-role>` tag in the deployment descriptor but the behaviour is unaffected

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems like I was missing a `WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml` file specifying a virtual host :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
  version="1.0">

  <virtual-host name="default_host" />

</web-bnd>
```

After that everything is working as expected.

What still puzzles me is that without the binding file the application still deploys successfully and the War module is shown to be associated to the virtual host `default_host` in the web console. And also that if the `web.xml` is present and contains security-constraint information, then the binding file is not necessary.